# Problem in filtering checkboxes with specific name suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of checkboxes with certain names suffix which i wanted to loop through. those checkboxes have some custom attribute which i wanted to mainupulate.there are other checboxes which i wanted to ignore.my current code is like this

name of suffix is IsCheckedCurrently

```
    $(document)
        .off("change", "#MyDropDown")
        .on("change", "#MyDropDown", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var teamKey = unescapeHtml($(this).val());

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                var teamKeys = $(this).attr('data-teamkeys');
                if (teamKeys != undefined) {
                    if (teamKeys != "") {

                        var ischeckPreviouslyItem = $("[name='" + $(this).attr('name').replace("IsCheckedCurrently", "IsCheckedPreviously") + "']");
                        if (teamKeys.includes(teamKey)) {
                            if (!this.checked) {
                                this.checked = true;
                                this.enabled = true;
                                ischeckPreviouslyItem.prop("checked", true);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (this.checked) {
                                this.checked = false;
                                ischeckPreviouslyItem.prop("checked", false)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    function unescapeHtml(safe) {
        return safe.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
            .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
            .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
            .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
    }
```

I have limited experteses in javascript as i am more of backend (.net C#) developer

following line i wanted to change which will include checkbox and name conditon

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {


<input type="checkbox" name="FIELD_PREFIX_9.IsCheckedCurrently" id="AHREF_9" checked="checked" value="true" >



 <script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What is the HTML that goes along with this so we can make sense of what you are doing? Can you state exactly what the code is supposed to be doing since the code is not very straightforward.

Comment: You have one input `name="fooIsCheckedCurrently"` and one that is `name="foo"`??

Comment: `if (teamKeys != undefined) {  if (teamKeys != "") {` could just be a truthy check `if (teamKeys) {}`

Comment: The selector `[name$=x]` matches a name that ends with `x`.

Comment: updated the question. checkboxes with names _modalCheckBoxes are needed in filter. other logic for name is for other purpose

Comment: @Barmar please let me know what change i do in  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () { to add [name$=x]  along with checkbox. also add it in answer so that i can accept

Comment: Where is the `_ModayCheckBoxes` suffix in that example?

Comment: i have changed the names of my checkboxes to IsCheckedCurrently. that's why i have shared it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

to

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name$="_ModayCheckBoxes"]')
```

to only match checkboxes whose name ends with that suffix.

See [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) documentation.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox][name$=_ModayCheckBoxes").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Box 1 <input type="checkbox" name="Foo_ModayCheckBoxes" value="foo">

<br> Box 2 <input type="checkbox" name="Bar_ModayCheckBoxes" value="bar">

<br> Box 3 <input type="checkbox" name="Something_Else" value="xxx"><br>
```

Comment: Have already tried it and were getting following error. Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox][name$=_ModayCheckBoxes]

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be needed in this case, but try adding quotes around the suffix.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error

Comment: Old version of jQuery?

Comment: using version 3.6

Comment: I have tried filtering with one checkbox exact name but that still not filtered  $('input[type=checkbox][name=FIELD_PREFIX_9.IsCheckedCurrently]').each(function () {

Comment: added one sample checkbox of mine and reference jquery i am using

Comment: I added a runnable snippet to my answer showing that it works.

Comment: it was quotation problem.  $("input[type=checkbox][name$='.IsCheckedCurrently']").each(function () { worked

Comment: Yes, you need quotes because it contains `.`